# How do I check if a directory exists in a Nushell script?

Tags: shell, file-io, nushell

I would like to know how I check if a directory exists in Nushell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `path exists` builtin.  Examples:

```
> "/home" | path exists
true
```

```
> "MRE" | path exists
false
```

```
> "./nu-0.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" | path exists
true
```

```
> [ '.', '/home', 'MRE'] | path exists
╭───┬───────╮
│ 0 │ true  │
│ 1 │ true  │
│ 2 │ false │
╰───┴───────╯
> [ '.', '/home', 'MRE'] | all {path exists}
false
> [ '.', '/home', 'MRE'] | any {path exists}
true
```

```
> if ([ '.', '/home', '/proc'] | all {path exists}) {
    "All directories exists"
} else {
    "One or more directories are missing"
}
All directories exists
```

<sup>(^Thanks to [@Raze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142716/raze) for the simplification using `all`.)</sup>

See `help path exists` for more details and `help path` for more path helper builtins.